# Stored procedure:Column name is not appearing while execute output parameters

Tags: sql-server

I have created one stored procedure which is output parameters.

```
create proc sp_withoutputparameter
@Gender nvarchar(50),
@employeecount int output
as
begin
select @employeecount=count(id) from temployee where gender=@Gender
end


declare @Totalcount int 
execute sp_withoutputparameter @employeecount=@Totalcount  out,@Gender='Female' 
print @Totalcount

execute sp_withoutputparameter @employeecount=@Totalcount  out,@Gender='Female' 
select @Totalcount
```

[Screen shot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghnbU.png) 
After executing the above queries. I am getting the results as showed in an attachments [Screen shot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/es9Oy.png)
On both queries I were used print and select in both results I am not getting a column name.

Please help me on this issue and what should I need do an amendments in an query for appear the column name???

Comment: It would help if we could see the actual procedure

Comment: http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Answer (score 1):

Since you're just outputting the variable as result, it won't have a column name. If you want to add one, just use an alias.

```
select @TotalCount as 'Total # of Female Employees'
```

Comment: It's working for select statement,and what about print statement??

Comment: SELECT returns results as a table, and PRINT just outputs messages to the log. If you want to add a label, just put a string in front of the variable. For example, print N'Total # of female employees = ' + CAST(@TotalCount as nvarchar(10))

Answer (score 0):

Looks like SQL Server, not MySQL, correct?  Since you're selecting/printing a variable, it doesn't have a "column" name to put in the header. Have you tried:

```
select @TotalCount as TotalCount
```

The print command doesn't have a header, nor should it.  It's meant to print a user defined message. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/print-transact-sql

You could do...

```
print '@totalCount'
print '------------'
print @totalCount
```

That's how you would get a header with TSQL print statement.

Comment: Hi Kevin,
for select statement it's working what about print statement.If I replace print instead of select I am getting an error. I wants to appear the column name in print statement as well.As I have attached the screen shot